# R - ggplot2 - bar chart - series get incorrect value labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a basic stack bar chart to present number of acceptations and rejections for n simulations. (one column)

**How can I control which series gets on the top of the stack together with corresponding value label?**

I tried two versions neither had worked. Either colors are wrong or the labels.

Version 1

```
#version 1
T <- c(1,0)
H0_Testing <- c("Accept","Reject")
Counter <- c(100,900)
Label= c("L","L")
barplotdata<- data.frame(H0_Testing,T,Counter,Label)
fill <- c("#E1B378","#5F9EA0")
chartlabels=c("Accepted1","Rejected1")
title="version 1"


#Ploting
ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=Counter,fill=factor(T)))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
  geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =Counter, y = Counter, size=4), show_guide = F)+   
  scale_fill_manual(labels=chartlabels, values=fill) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
  ggtitle(title)
```

Version 2

```
#version 2

    T <- c(0,1)
    H0_Testing <- c("Reject","Accept")
    Counter <- c(900,100)
    Label= c("L","L")
    barplotdata<- data.frame(H0_Testing,T,Counter,Label)
    fill <- c("#5F9EA0","#E1B378")
    chartlabels=c("Rejected2","Accepted2")
    title="version 2"

    #Ploting
    ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=Counter,fill=factor(T)))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
      geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =Counter, y = Counter, size=4), show_guide = F)+   
      scale_fill_manual(labels=chartlabels, values=fill) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
    ggtitle(title)
```

Comment: as a an aside `show_guide = F` is deprecated in favor of `show.legend = F`

Comment: actually you can get rid of that all together if you move the size option to outside the aesthetics call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Plot:

```
T <- c(0,1)
H0_Testing <- c("Reject","Accept")
Counter <- c(900,100)
Label= c("L","L")
barplotdata<- data.frame(H0_Testing,T,Counter,Label)
fill <- c("#5F9EA0","#E1B378")
chartlabels=c("Rejected2","Accepted2")
title="version 2"

ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=Counter,fill=rev(factor(Counter))))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
  geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =rev(factor(Counter)), size=4), show.legend = F)+   
  scale_fill_manual(labels=chartlabels, values=fill) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
  ggtitle(title)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=Counter,fill=factor(Counter)))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
      geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =rev(factor(Counter)), size=4), show.legend = F)+   
      scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Accepted2","Rejected2"), values=fill) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
    ggtitle(title)
```

[image]

Finally, if you want to switch the tiles:

```
ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=rev(Counter),fill=factor(Counter)))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
      geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =rev(factor(Counter)), size=4), show.legend = F)+   
      scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Rejected2","Accepted2"), values=fill) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
    ggtitle(title)
```

[image]

Note, for this third plot I added `y=rev(Counter)` in the aesthetics call.

as opposed to (your original plot Version 2):

```
    #Ploting
    ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=Counter,fill=factor(T)))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
      geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =Counter, y = Counter, size=4), show.legend = F)+   
      scale_fill_manual(labels=chartlabels, values=fill) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
    ggtitle(title)
```

[image]

The key difference for the bars is: `fill=rev(factor(T)` -notice that i reversed the factor level with the `rev()` command. For the text, notice that I removed `y=Counter` from `geom_text()` and changed the `label` value to `rev(factor(Counter))`. Also, for the second plot I manually set the legend items.

**UPDATE**

As per the OP's request in the comments, "I would like to change two more formats, decrease the font of the value labels and get rid of the T below x axis. Do you know how could I do the formatting?"

To decrease the font size, move `size` out of the aesthetics (you can also get rid of `show.legend=F` or `show_guide=F`). To get rid of the axis label you would add `theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+ylab("Counter")` -that removes the letter L and the tick mark which is what I  think you meant when you said T. The code for both within the `ggplot` call is:

```
ggplot(barplotdata,aes(x=Label,y=rev(Counter),fill=factor(Counter)))  + geom_bar(stat ="identity",width=.2)+
      geom_text(data=barplotdata, aes(label =rev(factor(Counter))),size=2)+   
      scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Rejected2","Accepted2"), values=fill) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size = 9), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 8),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size=8),axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),legend.text = element_text(size=7.5))+ 
    ggtitle(title)+theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())+ylab("Counter")
```

[image]

Comment: @ Cyrus Mohammadian value labels are still incorrect on your chart.(the 900 should be placed at the bottom).  A correct chart should present 900 rejections vs. 100 acceptances where colors should correspond to the value labels.

Comment: @Chris just made an additional edit too for the tiles

Comment: @ Cyrus Mohammadian where can I control the font of the value labels displayed on the series?

Comment: `scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Rejected2","Accepted2")` or reverse it `scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Accepted2","Rejected2")`

Comment: I see, I reversed the legend using 
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))  
I would like to change two more formats, decrease the font of the value labels and get rid of the T below x axis. Do you know how could I do the formatting?